# If statement in TableView Cell not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am calling data from a plist (copied to documents) which has a 0 or 1 value depending on whether I want a tickbox selected or not selected. The code in the cell.m file is as follows but I can't seem to get it to alter whether the tickbox is selected or not.

Main View code:

```
#import "ffguideViewController.h"
#import "booksCell.h"


@interface ffguideViewController ()

@end

@implementation ffguideViewController

{
    NSArray *title;
    NSArray *thumbnails;
    NSArray *price;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Find out the path of books_star.plist

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"books_star.plist"];

    // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    title = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
    thumbnails = [dict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    price = [dict objectForKey:@"price"];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [title count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *books_starTableIdentifier = @"booksCell";

    booksCell *cell = (booksCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:books_starTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"booksCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.titleLabel.text = [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.priceLabel.text = [price objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 104;
}

@end
```

Cell code:

```
#import "booksCell.h"

@implementation booksCell

@synthesize titleLabel = _titleLabel;
@synthesize priceLabel = _priceLabel;
@synthesize thumbnailImageView = _thumbnailImageView;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {}
return self;}


- (void) awakeFromNib {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"books_star.plist"];

    // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    NSString *checked = [dict objectForKey:@"check"];

    NSLog(@"%@", [[dict objectForKey:@"check"] class]);

    NSLog(@"Checked %@", checked);

    int checkedINT = [checked intValue];

     NSLog(@"CheckedInt %d", checkedINT);

    if (checkedINT == 1){
        checkedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_on.png"];
    } else {
        checkedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_off.png"];}}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


@end
```

plist:

```
    <key>title</key>
    <array>
        <string>Book 1</string>
        <string>Book 2</string>
        <string>Book 3</string>
        <string>Book 4</string>
        <string>Book 5</string>
        <string>Book 6</string>
    </array>
    <key>thumbnail</key>
    <array>
        <string>test.jpg</string>
        <string>test.jpg</string>
        <string>test.jpg</string>
        <string>testjpg</string>
        <string>test.jpg</string>
        <string>test.jpg</string>
        <string>test.jpg</string>
    </array>
    <key>price</key>
    <array>
        <string>£1.00</string>
        <string>£2.00</string>
        <string>£3.00</string>
        <string>£4.00</string>
        <string>£5.00</string>
        <string>£6.00</string>
        <string>£7.00</string>
    </array>
    <key>check</key>
    <array>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>0</string>
        <string>0</string>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>0</string>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>0</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I understand this may all be new to you but just a kind suggestion: If you haven't already, learn to use the debugger and NSLogs.  With the debugger, learn how to step through the code line-by-line, check variable values (while the app is running), set breakpoints, etc.  This will help take some of the mystery out of things "not working".

Comment: This code needs to be formatted :( how can you even read this with all the random brackets

Answer (score 2):

Move

```
 return self;
```

to the end of function not before your code runs.

Use breakpoints in future to even see if code is executed.

Regarding the second part of question coming out of our discussion:

You are creating a UITableViewCell from XIB (loadNibNamed). In this case initWithStyle: is not used. Instead of that implement your custom logic in:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
```

Comment: What you mean not working ? Did you debug it ? put breakpoint, print values. It's really simple code, should be so easy to find a problem if you have it running. How you create checkboxButton ? Xib or programatically ? Maybe it's nil.

Comment: I have an NS Log to show the value of 'checked' but nothing shows in the log. It's almost as if the function is not being seen or actioned.

Comment: How you create a Cell - update code with a table view delegates

Comment: The checkbox button is set in IB, as part of a cell for a table.

Comment: Btw why you have checkboxSelected variable in your logic instead of checking for button isSelected ?

Comment: I've posted the code for the main view and the cell. I have stopped the checkbox for now and am just trying to display a different image depending on whether a 1 or 0 is returned from the plist to get it working.

Comment: Almost there I think, but it's breaking at this line:

int checkedINT = [checked intValue]; - 

NS Log returns values of 0 and 1 correctly from the plist.

If I change the line to read either:

int checkedINT = 0;
int checkedINT = 1;

I get the correct images depending on the value.

Any ideas?

Comment: With what exception ? Maybe checked is not an NSString is your plist. Display NSLog(@"%@", [[dict objectForKey:@"check"] class])

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<booksCell 0x10962b6f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key checkboxButton.'

Comment: Oh wow that's definitely not breaking in the line you told me. Enable exception breakpoint in xcode to catch it. It look like you are trying to set "checkboxButton" property somewhere in your code - unfortunatelly you posted some old code in here, which doesnt have it.

Comment: Latest code uploaded. If I put a breakpoint in before that line it runs okay, to that point. As I say, if I force values of 1 or 0 it works fine and displays the correct image. (But I want different images in different cells depending on whether there's a 1 or 0 returned from the plist).

Comment: What is the output from NSLog(@"%@", [[dict objectForKey:@"check"] class]);

Comment: It returns: __NSCFArray

Comment: So why do you use NSString for it? Can you post a .plist code or screenshot from it ?

Comment: plist added to initial post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47970/discussion-between-grzegorz-krukowski-and-mark-stoneham)

Comment: Obviously its an NSArray.  If i'm not wrong, each object in this array should correspond a cell in a tableview. Whole array is not for a single cell.

Comment: Inside "checked" you have an array of objects so what you have to do is to use [[[dict objectForKey:@"checked"] objectAtIndex:index] intValue]; Probably you want to move the logic outside a cell itself and control it from tableview perspective where you can acctually get indexpath for a cell.